# How to change colour of path

Tags: lightning, design

[image]

Hi, I want to change the rejected status to turn red once clicked. Is this possible?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, you **cannot** change the color of the individual steps on Path component.

There are couple of ideas open for this:

- [Ability to change colours on the Sales path](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lK3MQAU)
- [New "Themes and Branding": Customize the Sales Path colour](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lKQ6QAM)
- [Enhancing Branding & Themes to include Path, Buttons, Menu Icons, & Text](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lKT0QAM)

Answer (score 1):

**For people who have searched and landed here for the standard colour options:**
**You can** change the general Colour of the Sales Path. Just not each Step individually.

Steps:

1. Nav to "**SETUP**"
2. Nav to "**Themes and Branding**"
3. Create a **custom theme**
4. **Adjust the Brand Colour**, this will become your completed Stages Colour the other 2 colours will be based on your brand colour.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the color of the existing path but if you create your own LWC or Aura component, you can define the CSS like so:

```
<aura:html tag="style">
    :root {
        --lwc-colorBackgroundPathComplete: rgb(75, 202, 129) !important;
    }
    .slds-path__nav .slds-is-complete {
        background-color: rgb(75, 202, 129) !important;
    }
</aura:html>
```

...and you'll get your desired colors.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can apply css on standard class like below and it's work

Aura :-
<aura:component
implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId"

> 

<aura:attribute name="bgColorCodeComplete" type="String" default="#33B615" />
<aura:attribute name="bgColorCodeIncomplete" type="String" default="#33B615" />
<aura:attribute name="bgColorCodeActive" type="String" default="#33B615" />
<aura:attribute name="bgColorCodeButton" type="String" default="#33B615" />
<aura:attribute name="isnotview" type="Boolean" default="false" />

<aura:html tag="style">
:root { --lwc-colorBackgroundPathComplete:{!v.bgColorCodeComplete} !important; }
.slds-path__nav .slds-is-complete {
background-color: {!v.bgColorCodeComplete}!important;
}

```
  :root { --lwc-colorBackgroundPathIncomplete:{!v.bgColorCodeIncomplete} !important; }
  .slds-path__nav .slds-is-incomplete {
  background-color: {!v.bgColorCodeIncomplete}!important;
  }
  
   :root { --lwc-colorBackgroundPathActive:{!v.bgColorCodeActive} !important; }
  .slds-path__nav .slds-is-active {
  background-color: {!v.bgColorCodeActive}!important;
  }
  
  .slds-button--brand{
  background-color: {!v.bgColorCodeButton}!important;
  }
```

</aura:html>
</aura:component>

JS:-

({
colorBgApply : function(component, event, helper) {
console.log('event.getParam('colorInpCodeVal')'+event.getParam('colorInpCodeVal'));
component.set("v.bgColorCodeComplete",event.getParam('colorInpCodeVal'));
component.set("v.bgColorCodeIncomplete",event.getParam('colorInpCodeVal'));
component.set("v.bgColorCodeActive",event.getParam('colorInpCodeVal'));
component.set("v.bgColorCodeButton",event.getParam('colorInpCodeVal'));

```
}
```

})

Design :-

design:component
<design:attribute name="bgColorCodeComplete" label="Colour Picker For Complete Stage"/>
<design:attribute name="bgColorCodeIncomplete" label="Colour Picker For Incomplete Stage"/>
<design:attribute name="bgColorCodeActive" label="Colour Picker For Active Stage"/>
<design:attribute name="bgColorCodeButton" label="Colour Picker For Button"/>

</design:component>